# Can't connect to oracle:12.1.0.2 outside docker container

Tags: linux, oracle, docker, oracle12c

oracle container last log:

```
SQL> Mon Sep 30 06:06:45 2019
Shutting down instance (immediate)
Stopping background process SMCO
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Mon Sep 30 06:06:46 2019
Stopping background process CJQ0
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 13
Mon Sep 30 06:06:48 2019
Stopping Job queue slave processes, flags = 7
Mon Sep 30 06:06:48 2019
Job queue slave processes stopped
All dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
ALTER DATABASE CLOSE NORMAL
Mon Sep 30 06:06:50 2019
Mon Sep 30 06:06:50 2019
SMON: disabling tx recoveryStopping Emon pool

Stopping Emon pool
Mon Sep 30 06:06:50 2019
SMON: disabling cache recovery
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
Mon Sep 30 06:06:51 2019
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
Mon Sep 30 06:06:51 2019
Thread 1 closed at log sequence 21
Successful close of redo thread 1
Completed: ALTER DATABASE CLOSE NORMAL
ALTER DATABASE DISMOUNT
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
Completed: ALTER DATABASE DISMOUNT
Mon Sep 30 06:06:52 2019
ARCH: Archival disabled due to shutdown: 1089
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 30-SEP-2019 06:08:37

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/97ffb86e57bb/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                30-SEP-2019 06:08:38
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/97ffb86e57bb/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Sep 30 06:08:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610612736 bytes
Fixed Size                  2924928 bytes
Variable Size             520097408 bytes
Database Buffers         1073741824 bytes
Redo Buffers               13848576 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
#########################
DATABASE IS READY TO USE!
#########################
The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
AQPC started with pid=30, OS id=89 
Database Characterset for PDB$SEED is AL32UTF8
Opening pdb PDB$SEED (2) with Resource Manager plan: DEFAULT_PLAN
Database Characterset for ORCLPDB1 is AL32UTF8
Opening pdb ORCLPDB1 (3) with Resource Manager plan: DEFAULT_PLAN
Pluggable database ORCLPDB1 opened read write
Starting background process CJQ0
Mon Sep 30 06:08:48 2019
CJQ0 started with pid=31, OS id=199 
Completed: ALTER DATABASE OPEN
Mon Sep 30 06:08:49 2019
Shared IO Pool defaulting to 64MB. Trying to get it from Buffer Cache for process 61.
===========================================================
Dumping current patch information
===========================================================
No patches have been applied
===========================================================
Mon Sep 30 06:08:49 2019
db_recovery_file_dest_size of 4560 MB is 0.00% used. This is a
user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
Mon Sep 30 06:44:13 2019
Warning: VKTM detected a time drift.
Time drifts can result in an unexpected behavior such as time-outs. Please check trace file for more details.
```

inside container:

[image]

and it's work correctly inside:

[image]

docker ps on my machine:

[image]

ports on my machine:
[image]

when I try to connect:
[image]

What should I do, to fix this problem?

UPDATE:

I find the difference in log file right now:

-when the container isn't work properly:

```
db_recovery_file_dest_size of 4560 MB is 0.00% used. This is a
user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
Warning: VKTM detected a time drift.
Time drifts can result in an unexpected behavior such as time-outs. Please check trace file for more details.
Stopping container.
SIGTERM received, shutting down database!
```

-now, when everything looks fine:

```
db_recovery_file_dest_size of 4560 MB is 0.00% used. This is a
user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
Mon Sep 30 09:19:22 2019
Closing scheduler window
Restoring Resource Manager plan DEFAULT_PLAN via scheduler window
Setting Resource Manager plan DEFAULT_PLAN at pdb ORCLPDB1 (3) via parameter
Mon Sep 30 09:21:31 2019
XDB installed.
XDB initialized.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `docker ps` it seems like the port bind with `127.0.0.1:1521`.

How you start the container?

It should not bind with localhost, so It should be like:

```
0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp
```

As you mentioned it works correctly inside the container than something wrong with docker run command.

I tried it with below command or double-check the [configuration](https://dzone.com/articles/oracle-12c-image-installation-in-docker):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 --name OracleDB oracle
```

**Update:**

If above did not resolve the issue then its something wrong the oracle docker image which also addressed in this [issue](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/412) or [oracle_database-issue-4108894](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/4108894.html).

Or you can follow step of @Alex.

> I created container followed these steps ["Running Oracle Database
>   Enterprise and Standard Edition 2 in a Docker container" After](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance) it was
>   initialized, container worked fine before I reboot my machine. Then
>   happened what I described above. Now I restarted the container with
>   better wi-fi connection and it's working fine.

Comment: I think it's not a problem.
I created container followed these steps ["Running Oracle Database Enterprise and Standard Edition 2 in a Docker container"](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance)
After it was initialized, container worked fine before I reboot my machine. Then happened what I described above.
Now I restarted the container with better wi-fi connection and it's working fine.

Comment: I found something, please, look at the "UPDATE" part of my question

Comment: `SIGTERM received, shutting down database!` it just receive signal from stoping in this log

Comment: I'm about:
'Warning: VKTM detected a time drift.
Time drifts can result in an unexpected behavior such as time-outs. Please check trace file for more details.'
Can difference in time be a problem? (the difference is 3 hours between my machine and oracle container)

Comment: are you using VM? https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/preview/en/2745258 and you mentioned that now you are able to connect?

Comment: yes, right now I can connect to oracle trough docker from my machine to container and I didn't do anything.
And difference in time is still about 3 hours.

Comment: that good, I update the answer there is two open issue regarding this which might cause to this issue and both are still open https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/4108894.html, also I added your comment in answer so may help other